# Match lines beginning with the same pattern in two text files

Tags: sed, awk, grep, string

I am now having two text files with some of the lines beginning with the same pattern. For example,

File A

```
1Mo 1,1 I love you.
1Mo 1,2 I like you.
Hi 23,3 I am hungry.
Hi 23,4 I am foolish.
```

File B

```
1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
Hi 23,5 Ich habe Durst.
Hi 23,6 Ich bin neu.
```

File A and File B have two lines starting with the same pattern "1Mo 1,1" and "1Mo 1,2", respectively. My expected output is like this:

```
1Mo 1,1 I love you.
1Mo 1,2 I like you.
1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
```

My idea is that I should use grep to extract the beginning pattern of each line in file A then using these patterns to match each line in file B. I tried to write a grep command as follows, but it failed:

```
grep "^[.A-z]*\s[.]*\s" file A > extract.txt
```

This is the command I searched the community and adapted to use for the string matching in file B:

> while read string; do grep "$string" file B; done < extract.txt

Is anybody having some idea about how to do the grep thing for pattern extraction and matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files:

```
> cat a
1Mo 1,1 I love you.
1Mo 1,2 I like you.
1Mo 1,3 I am hungry.
1Mo 1,4 I am foolish.

> cat b
1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
1Mo 1,5 Ich habe Durst.
1Mo 1,6 Ich bin neu.
```

Find the common lines that share the first two words (space separated):

```
> awk '{print $1 " " $2}' a > find
> grep -f find b | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' > find2
```

Now find all lines that match just those patterns:

```
> grep -f find2 a b
a:1Mo 1,1 I love you.
a:1Mo 1,2 I like you.
b:1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
b:1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
```

Finaly, filter the filename:

```
> grep -f find2 a b | sed 's/^[^:]*://'
1Mo 1,1 I love you.
1Mo 1,2 I like you.
1Mo 1,1 Ich liebe dich.
1Mo 1,2 Ich mag dich.
```

Comment: Many thx! This solves my problem and I will try this on my whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Grep excepts more than one argument and you could use this simple pattern by your examples.

```
grep -Eh '1,1|1,2' "File A" "File B"
```

Comment: Thx, but not all the lines that begin with 1.1 or 1.2. The pattern is overlapping in two files,and always changing.